# GCloud import vmdk disk always failing

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, esxi

I'm trying to upload some of my ESXI VMs to Google Cloud. I have exported all VMs using ESXI tools and have got 3 .vmdk files. One of these files uploads without issues, the other two, however, throw the following error and then fail:

```
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.import) build 6683803d-6947-46c3-951e-20da0e529c07 completed with status "FAILURE"
```

I have followed this guide to import my disks: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks

It says CentOS 8 (which the VMs are running) is supported, so I guess no issue there. I have not found anything similar, so I hope someone here has had this issue and has been able t solve it.

### Edit

I have found that it tries to set the image size to 1024GB (I don't know why), could this have anything to do with it. It also throws the error:

```
"ImportFailed: Failed to resize disk. The Compute Engine default service account needs the role: roles/compute.storageAdmin'"
```

It does have the role, however.

Comment: Have you deleted VMware Tools before importing images?

Comment: I do not have them installed

Comment: Did you attempt to provide the default service account the role mentioned in the error? If so, did it work? If not, what is the new error message you receive?

Comment: Yes I did. There was no new error, it kept telling me I lacked the permission. I proceeded to give all accounts all permissions. It still gave me the same error (lack of permission error). I have found out that when you select a thin provisioned disk (in esxi), google will automatically take the maximum size, as if it was thick provisioned (in this case 1TB). I think I am not allowed to upload 1 TB. When trying with a thick provisoned disk of 16GB everything is fine (well another error but that's for another thread)